# bugzilla how to serach by group

Tags: bugzilla

how to search bugs which is report by user in a given group?

we need statistics bugs by department.
I use Group to represent department.
Or is there another solution to give all user a department attribute?

Comment: Hi @ttqs is there not a way to navigate through the db?

Comment: this is ok.I`m new in Bugzilla.I prefer to solve it by the feature provided.

Comment: have you tried that -> https://maestrano.com/knowledge_center/pages/29-bugzilla-tutorial-get-started @ttqs?

Answer (score 0):

agree with Andy K. I think, the simple solution is query in bugzilla db. But so may be bugzilla report tool could provide the report by user group?